Add Rows Function for Smartsheet API Not working
I have a sheet where i have 2 columns. I have Customer and Item.

In Customer Column I have a list of customers already

In Item column I want the code to add 5 rows under each customer with item names that i want for example
 * Customer *                      * ITEM *



row 1    Office
row 2                                          Shop
row 3                                       Logistics
row 4                                      Constructions
row 5                                      Mapping
row 6                                       Cartoon
row 7  Office 2
row 8                                        Shop
row 9                                       Logistics
row 10                                      Constructions
row 11                                       Mapping
row 12                                      Cartoon
However, when ever I am running my code it says Rows added successfully for all customers with the specified items. But for some reason in smartsheet my data doesn't show up?
# Specify the sheet ID
sheet_id = ''

# Define column IDs
CUSTOMER_COLUMN_ID = ''
ITEM_COLUMN_ID = ''

# Define the specific items to add under each customer
specific_items = [
    "Shop",
    "Construction",
    "Manager",
    "Logistics",
    "Load"
]

# Fetch the existing sheet
sheet = ss_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)

# Collect unique customers from the current data
unique_customers = set()
for row in sheet.rows:
    for cell in row.cells:
        if cell.column_id == CUSTOMER_COLUMN_ID and cell.value:
            unique_customers.add(cell.value)

# Prepare new rows to add for each customer
rows_to_add = []

for customer in unique_customers:
    for item in specific_items:
        new_row = ss_client.models.Row()
        new_row.to_bottom = True  # Add to the bottom of the sheet

        # Create cells for each column
        new_row.cells.append({
            'column_id': CUSTOMER_COLUMN_ID,
            'value': customer
        })
        new_row.cells.append({
            'column_id': ITEM_COLUMN_ID,
            'value': item
        })

        rows_to_add.append(new_row)

# Add the new rows in chunks
chunk_size = 300
for start in range(0, len(rows_to_add), chunk_size):
    response = ss_client.Sheets.add_rows(sheet_id, rows_to_add[start:start + chunk_size])
    if response.message:
        print(response.message)  # Print the response message

print("Rows added successfully for all customers with the specified items.")

